# URI based Elasticsearch query with "starts with" filter

Tags: elasticsearch

For example, I would like to search for all  the names that *starts with* `Na`. How do I specify   that in the URI based query?

> localhost:9200/index/type/_search?XXX

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this. Hope that helps you

```
http://localhost:9200/index/type/_search?q=names:na*
```